# SQL Server - Update table without knowing the column just the value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hope someone will help me with my problem ...

How can I update my table with this: I have the value eg. '`April 28, 2017`'

And I need to find the column containing that value.

My columns looks like this:

```
train_date | train_date1 | train_date2 | train_date3 | train_date4 | train_date5 | train_date6
```

Then the table(s) contained that value will be updated to `NULL`.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like a horrible table design... Why not one date per row?

Comment: what do you mean by the 'table(s) contained that value will be updated'? Do you mean columns to be updated containing that value ?

Comment: thanks sir @Unnikrishnan thats what I mean

Comment: thanks sir marc_s :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to update column containing particular value to **NULL** ? Then you can use **CASE** condition to check if column contains that value then update it to **NULL** else leave it as it is.

```
UPDATE traintable
SET train_date = CASE WHEN train_date  = 'April 28, 2017' THEN NULL ELSE train_date  END,
train_date1 = CASE WHEN train_date1  = 'April 28, 2017' THEN NULL ELSE train_date1  END,
train_date2 = CASE WHEN train_date2  = 'April 28, 2017' THEN NULL ELSE train_date2  END,
train_date3 = CASE WHEN train_date3  = 'April 28, 2017' THEN NULL ELSE train_date3  END,
train_date4 = CASE WHEN train_date4  = 'April 28, 2017' THEN NULL ELSE train_date4  END,
train_date5 = CASE WHEN train_date5  = 'April 28, 2017' THEN NULL ELSE train_date5  END,
train_date6 = CASE WHEN train_date6  = 'April 28, 2017' THEN NULL ELSE train_date6  END
```

Comment: That's really what I need . .